# Communication between Firebird database and Android app

Tags: android, sql, firebird

I am new to Android app's and what I want to accomplish is connection between Firebird database which is located on computer that has static IP address and android app which has access to internet.

How I can achieve this, and if possible explain it detailed.

Comment: There was an old Jaybird for Android fork, but it seems abandoned because no one needed it enough to care

Comment: Don't connect to a Firebird database directly from an Android application, define a REST (or other web service) API that queries Firebird in your favourite server language, and have your Android app talk to that web service. It will be safer (the application can only use a well-defined API, and someone reverse-engineering your app won't have direct access to your database), more performant (Firebird's wire protocol is rather chatty and not so great with high latency connections), and you can keep your app itself simpler.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i have read about REST and have idea how it works but i do not know how to use it. Is there anything you could point me out to go and read about?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ok, i managed to find and test REST and successfully connected to GIT HUB api to test it. Problem now is how should i connect to my firebird database?

Comment: That depends on what language you'll use the write your REST web service, which would be a different question (and one that is likely already answered in the documentation of the driver and/or platform you'll use for developing your REST service).

Comment: Thanks. If it is not problem to you, would you recommend me some documentation on writing my REST web service in C# (if that is option) or give me some others for other languages

Comment: Found documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api#Exercise1). Thanks.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel is there any way I can msg you (not to create new question) for something I think you could help me if you have time

Comment: No, sorry, I don't do that.